# Publishing larger items stuck at transporting phase for long time and getting failed

Tags: web8.5, deployer, discovery-service, publishingfailed, transport

When Publishing larger items(>100MB) stuck at transporting phase for long time and getting  failed.

We have 4 publishers running with 2 Rendering, 2 Deploying threads on each server

We have 1 deployer.

Currently, we have applied CD_8.5.0.6435 hot fix and increased the SendTimeout to "960000 ms" in cd_transport.config suggested by SDL support still the same issue persist.

Before that SDL support team suggested to apply hot fix CD_8.5.0.3725 to resolve issue but this also didn't help us out.

These failures happen in the "Transporting" phase.

Transport log errors:

```
 2018-11-02 06:45:40,075 DEBUG StepPrepare - Zipping has been completed successfully for transaction: tcm:0-2383794-66560
2018-11-02 06:45:40,121 INFO  ParallelTransportWorker - Scheduling sending TransportPackage to destinations for transaction: tcm:0-2383794-66560
2018-11-02 06:45:40,121 DEBUG DestinationControllerFactory - Returning existing destination controller.
2018-11-02 06:45:40,121 DEBUG ParallelTransportWorker - TransportPackage transport has been scheduled, blocking and waiting for result for transaction: tcm:0-2383794-66560
2018-11-02 06:45:40,121 DEBUG ParallelDestinationWorker - Waiting for transport result for: tcm:0-2383794-66560
2018-11-02 06:45:40,121 DEBUG TransportSender - Starting TransportSender for transportPackage D:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\bin\transactions\tcm_0-2383794-66560.Content.zip and destination OnvfQIG9nRtElNqYzK9fzg==. 
    2018-11-02 06:45:40,137 DEBUG TransportPoolManager - Returning a freely available and alive TransportConnector
2018-11-02 06:45:40,137 DEBUG TransportSender - Starting sending of transportPackage D:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\bin\transactions\tcm_0-2383794-66560.Content.zip to destination OnvfQIG9nRtElNqYzK9fzg==. 
2018-11-02 06:49:40,219 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 06:49:40,219 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 240098, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 06:54:40,223 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 06:54:40,223 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 540102, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 06:59:40,216 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 06:59:40,216 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 840095, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 07:01:40,137 ERROR ParallelDestinationWorker - Timeout of 960000 ms exceeded for transaction tcm:0-2383794-66560
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) at com.tridion.transport.workers.ParallelDestinationWorker.blockAndGetResult(ParallelDestinationWorker.java:109)
at 
 com.tridion.transport.workers.ParallelTransportWorker.doWork(ParallelTransportWorker.java:49)
at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.StepTransport.execute(StepTransport.java:54)
at com.tridion.transport.model.transaction.context.StepPrepare.lambda$execute$0(StepPrepare.java:57)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018-11-02 07:01:40,137 DEBUG BaseHTTPSTransportConnector - Aborting current post to http://*****:9084/httpupload
2018-11-02 07:01:40,137 DEBUG BaseHTTPSTransportConnector - Aborted current post to http://*****:9084/httpupload
2018-11-02 07:01:40,137 DEBUG BaseHTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute: send on destination: http://*****:9084/httpupload due to: java.net.SocketException. Attempt=1; MaxRetries=5; Exception: Socket closed
2018-11-02 07:04:40,215 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 07:04:40,215 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 1140094, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 07:09:40,227 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 07:09:40,227 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 1440106, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 07:14:40,229 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 07:14:40,229 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 1740108, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 07:19:40,229 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 07:19:40,229 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 2040108, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 07:24:40,229 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 07:24:40,229 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 2340108, Notifications: true
2018-11-02 07:29:40,231 DEBUG DestinationControllerMonitor - Cleaning up destination controllers.
2018-11-02 07:29:40,231 DEBUG DestinationController - Idle(ms): 2640110, Notifications: true
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

Deployer logs

```
2018-12-20 10:31:20,189 DEBUG AbstractFolderAutoCreator - D:\SDL\Web\live\deployer\incoming is already created. Skipping the creation
2018-12-20 10:31:20,252 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Initializing Legacy step configuration Map
2018-12-20 10:31:20,252 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=TridionBootstrap, Id=Tridion-Bootstrap, Verb=Content,Prepare,Commit,Rollback)[Steps[Step(Id=TridionUnzipStep)]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,252 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=Deploy,Undeploy, Id=Tridion-Wait, Verb=Wait)[Steps[Step(Id=TridionWaitStep)]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,252 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=Deploy, Id=Tridion-Process-Deploy, Verb=Process)[Steps[Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=SchemaDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.SchemaDeploy, Type=SchemaDeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=PageDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageDeploy, Type=PageDeploy)[Transformer(Class=com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer)]], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=BinaryDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.BinaryDeploy, Type=BinaryDeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=ComponentDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentDeploy, Type=ComponentDeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=TemplateDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.TemplateDeploy, Type=TemplateDeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=PublicationDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.PublicationDeploy, Type=PublicationDeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=TaxonomyDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyDeploy, Type=TaxonomyDeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=ComponentPresentationDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy, Type=ComponentPresentationDeploy)[Transformer(Class=com.tridion.transformer.TCDLDefaultTransformer)]], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=StructureGroupDeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupDeploy, Type=StructureGroupDeploy)]]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,252 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=Undeploy, Id=Tridion-Process-Undeploy, Verb=Process)[Steps[Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=PageUndeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.PageUndeploy, Type=PageUndeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=ComponentPresentationUndeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationUndeploy, Type=ComponentPresentationUndeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=TaxonomyUndeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.TaxonomyUndeploy, Type=TaxonomyUndeploy)], Step(Factory=com.sdl.delivery.deployer.steps.TridionExecutableStepFactory, Id=StructureGroupUndeploy)[Module(Class=com.tridion.deployer.modules.StructureGroupUndeploy, Type=StructureGroupUndeploy)]]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,267 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=Deploy,Undeploy, Id=Tridion-PreCommit-TX, Verb=PreCommit)[Steps[Step(Id=TridionPreCommitStep)]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,267 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=Deploy,Undeploy, Id=Tridion-Commit-TX, Verb=Commit)[Steps[Step(Id=TridionCommitStep)[RetryPoint(PipelineId=Tridion-PreCommit-TX, StepId=TridionPreCommitStep)]]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,267 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=Deploy,Undeploy, Id=Tridion-Rollback-TX, Verb=Rollback)[Steps[Step(Id=TridionRollbackStep)]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,267 DEBUG TridionExecutableStepFactory - Creating Legacy configuration map for Steps of pipeline Pipeline(Action=Deploy,Undeploy, Finalize=true, Id=Tridion-Cleanup, Verb=*)[Steps[Step(Id=TridionCleanupStep)]]
2018-12-20 10:31:20,345 INFO  AkkaConfiguration - Creating actor system
2018-12-20 10:31:20,361 INFO  AkkaConfiguration - Configuring Akka min: 10, max: 30 values for thread-pool-executor based on deployer queues worker configuration
2018-12-20 10:31:21,205 INFO  PipelineConfigurationLoaderImpl - Loading default pipelines
2018-12-20 10:31:21,283 DEBUG ConfigUtil - Could not get Property ContentQueue for Queue Id Workers. Message : Could not find property: Workers 
2018-12-20 10:31:21,283 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Configuring Queue: [ContentQueue] polling interval: 1000 ms. workers: 10
2018-12-20 10:31:21,283 DEBUG ConfigUtil - Could not get Property CommitQueue for Queue Id Workers. Message : Could not find property: Workers 
2018-12-20 10:31:21,283 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Configuring Queue: [CommitQueue] polling interval: 1000 ms. workers: 10
2018-12-20 10:31:21,283 DEBUG ConfigUtil - Could not get Property PrepareQueue for Queue Id Workers. Message : Could not find property: Workers 
2018-12-20 10:31:21,283 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Configuring Queue: [PrepareQueue] polling interval: 1000 ms. workers: 10
2018-12-20 10:31:21,486 INFO  DefaultQueueManager - License is valid. Starting the Queue Handler.
2018-12-20 10:31:21,486 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Starting command queue poller for queue: com.sdl.delivery.deployer.queue.filesystem.FSDeployerQueue@675bf541
2018-12-20 10:31:21,486 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Starting command queue poller for queue: com.sdl.delivery.deployer.queue.filesystem.FSDeployerQueue@779ef5cb
2018-12-20 10:31:21,486 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Starting command queue poller for queue: com.sdl.delivery.deployer.queue.filesystem.FSDeployerQueue@43cc7951
2018-12-20 10:31:21,486 INFO  DefaultQueueManager - Deployer Engine queues started.
2018-12-20 10:31:22,111 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Queue [Id=CommitQueue]. Starting Command Queue Poller
2018-12-20 10:31:22,111 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Starting Command Queue Poller
2018-12-20 10:31:22,111 INFO  CommandQueuePoller - Queue [Id=PrepareQueue]. Starting Command Queue Poller
2018-12-20 10:31:27,417 INFO  DeployerLegacyEndpointController - Deployer Endpoint started.
```

Before

```
<BinaryStorage Id="PackageStorage" Adapter="FileSystem">
    <Property Name="Path" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\deployer\incoming" />
  </BinaryStorage>


<Queues>
    <Queue Default="true" Verbs="Content" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="ContentQueue">
      <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\deployer\queue" />
    </Queue>
    <Queue Verbs="Commit,Rollback" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="CommitQueue">
      <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\deployer\queue\FinalTX" />
    </Queue>
    <Queue Verbs="Prepare" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="PrepareQueue">
      <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\deployer\queue\Prepare" />
    </Queue>
```

After

```
<BinaryStorage Id="PackageStorage" Adapter="FileSystem">
    <Property Name="Path" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\incoming" />
  </BinaryStorage>


<Queues>
    <Queue Default="true" Verbs="Content" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="ContentQueue">
      <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\queue" />
    </Queue>
    <Queue Verbs="Commit,Rollback" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="CommitQueue">
      <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\queue\FinalTX" />
    </Queue>
    <Queue Verbs="Prepare" Adapter="FileSystem" Id="PrepareQueue">
      <Property Name="Destination" Value="D:\SDL\Web\live\queue\Prepare" />
    </Queue>
```

Comment: Just a thought, it's possible that the issue lies on the Deployer side, e.g. the HTTP max request size setting might be too small. Take a dig through some of the older posts circa 2010-2013 where this was a configuration issue with older Tridion versions. Could be the same thing wrapped in a different exception message.

Comment: Also look for some clues in the Deployer log.

Comment: @nickoli In deployer application.properties HTTP max request size is 100Mb

Comment: Looks like that is your problem then.

Comment: Sorry that is typo mistake in deployer application properties HTTP max request size is 1000MB and max-file-size=1000Mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing was failing due to the following reasons:

The page path, file name was too long due to that page was failing, I didn't change 
that path/file name of the page in the CMS, but shorten the incoming path and binary storage in the deployer server then the page publishing got succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to look like still your package size still larger than 100MB

Try following steps to troubleshoot to fix:

**Content Manager**

1. Capture that Large published transport package item by Modify your **cd_transport_conf.xml**, add a "**Cleanup**" attribute with the value of **false** to the Workfolder element:

> <WorkFolder Location="./transactions" NotificationBatchSize="10"
>   **Cleanup="false"**/>

The packages will appear in [Tridion-Home]\bin\transactions.

2. Find out the size of the transport package file which getting failed, adjust the upload size in the deployed service.
3. Worth review this **cd_transport_conf.xml** config timeout values.

> <Polling MaxAttempts="900" Timeout="15" Interval="5000"/>
>
> <Senders SendTimeout="960000"/>

Restart the transport service for this change to take effect.

**Content Delivery:**

In your deployer service **application.properties** file to increase the maximum size permitted for uploaded/allowed for files requests according to your maximum package size requirements

> spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1000Mb
>
> spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=1000Mb

Clean up the package incoming folders and Restart your deployer for these changes to take effect.

**DONT FORGET TO REVERT** **cd_transport_conf.xml**, "**Cleanup**" attribute property once your issue got resolved.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry that is typo mistake in deployer application properties HTTP max request size is 1000MB and max-file-size=1000Mb and tried all the steps whichever you have mentioned before raising question . The packages size are 876MB, 312MB

Comment: SDL Support team asked us to  increase the <Senders SendTimeout="9600000"/> in cd_trasnport_conf.xml it works for large items but still failing for some of the items file size  890MB. If we increase SendTimeout  again will it cause any performance issue.

Comment: Looks like then it's not a timeout issue, still, you are getting the same error message

Comment: yes still i am getting the same error message :                                             ERROR BaseHTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to send TransportPackage to url: http://cdlive-dev.abc.org.uk:1044/httpupload cause: HTTP/1.1 500

Comment: Looks response code 500 internal server error on deployer service side, Any error in the deployer logs?

Comment: Added deployer logs in the question can you please take look and let me know your inputs.Thanks for your support

Comment: The above issue got resolved by changing the binary storage and queue incoming path values. Can you please let us know do you have any characters restrictions on this file path?

I have updated my question with deployer configuration changes which resolved the issue

Comment: AFAIK, No, but not sure, looks like something those folders not cleaned up properly, maybe worth delete all the folders and content as well as clean up all the folders and files start with tcm and .tmp files under c:\Windows\temp

Comment: The specified path, file name, or both are too long due to that page was failing I have shorten the binary storage and incoming path then this page publishing succeeded.

Comment: okay, then it's confirmed path restriction, I think that unzip feature has restrictions for the path.